# Expressing the 0 vector as a non trivial linear combination of 3 vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I understand that with most vectors to express them as a linear combination you can use the sort of method shown [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGgT9.png) but with the zero vector surely everything in the $ w$  column is a $0$ so you can't get the $x$,$ y$ and $z$ values, only trivial combinations.

> Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I just
> want to know how to do the first step really not the whole thing.
> Thanks in advance.

Edit: Trying to use Gauss jordan algorithm for it.
Edit: I have been given the three vectors to use but I don't want the full answer just how to do the next step so I can do it myself

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does it matter whether that column is all zeroes? (Hint: the answer is it doesn't matter one bit - the fow-reduction algorithm for the general solution doesn't require a non-zero column of constants...)

Comment: @CyclotomicField So at first I tried the method like shown in the picture but quickly realised that with the zero vector that won't get me anywhere. I then tried something more like a system of 3 equations but that strays away from the guass jordan algorithm which I'm trying to use.

Comment: So if you have $x$ and $y$ and you're trying to find scalars $a$ and $b$ so that $ax+by=z$ then you can write down all of the components and solve the system for $a$ and $b$. No solutions means it can't be done, infinitely many means all three are on the same line, otherwise you'll get a unique solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm not sure I follow. If I am looking for a solution along the lines of xu+yv+zw (u,v,w being the vectors I have been given) I thought the XYZ values would be in that column? I don't understand how else to get them if not from that column?

Comment: Of interest, the linked image seems to be lifted directly from [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/ZtPWtEh5BQE?t=87).  What was unsatisfactory about the video's explanation itself?

Comment: @JMoravitz It is from that video yes, but that video relies on the column having at least one non zero constant  unless I've completely misunderstood

Comment: @CyclotomicField I'll give that a shot now thank you

Comment: Apparently you have completely misunderstood and/or you have not row reduced properly.  When you row reduce [you get this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C3%2C-11%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C4%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C-2%7D%2C%7B-1%2C1%2C-9%7D%7D), same as the video gets, which *does* have nonzero entries in the third column... as desired

Comment: @JMoravitz As I am looking to express the zero vector as a linear combination that doesn't seem to work? I'm not attempting the question in that video, just used that screenshot to show I was aware of the traditional way of doing it but was having trouble applying that method to the zero vector

Comment: @CyclotomicField Having done that I think it has only given me the trivial result of a=0, b=0 and c=0?

Comment: If you were left only with pivots, then yes that is what it would imply.  If you were to do that here for these three vectors and trying to find what linear combination*s* of them make the zero vector... reading the result of the row reduction that reads as "the third vector could have any coefficient, call it $t$" and then "the first vector has coefficient -4 times $t$" and "the second vector has coefficient $5$ times $t$".  That is, $-4tu+5tv+tw=0$ for every value of $t$

Comment: What you are asking for, finding sets of solutions for making linear combinations that result in the zero vector, is precisely what is being talked about when we refer to the "*kernel*" or "*nullspace*" of a matrix or transformation.  This should be strongly emphasized in any textbook or lecture series (*or left-nullspace depending on orientation of the matrix, if your vectors in question are the rows or are the columns*)

Comment: It sounds as though you'd have problems applying Gauss-Jordan just to the system $x+y=0$. If so you simply need to learn how to find the general solution to a system of equations. Make certain to review this before the final

Comment: To emphasize... here, we had learned from the video and its method that $w = 4u-5v$.  All we really did was subtract $w$ to the other side and multiply both sides by $t$ to get $4tu-5tv-tw=0$... it didn't require any manipulations that you didn't have access to before

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much, I'm really sorry to have taken up so much of your time, I think I've somehow got to this stage without ever really thinking about the t coefficient but that was the missing piece. Thank you again and sorry to have taken so much time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep saying that that zero vector causes problems, so you can't get anywhere. In fact those zeroes are no problem at all.

A similar problem (which is really more than I should provide here, since there are similar problems worked out earlier in the book): Express the zero vector as a non-trivial linear  combination of $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$:

We want a non-trivial solution to $x(1,2)+y(2,4)=(0,0)$. That says $$\begin{align}x+2y&=0
\\2x+4y&=0.\end{align}$$

You are supposed to know a procedure for finding the general solution to any system of linear equations. If you simply apply that algorithm you find the general solution is $$x=-2t, y=t,$$where $t$ is a parameter. (If you don't know how I got that solution you're in big trouble in your linear algebra course! You need need need to seriously review a few earlier sections on solving linear equations!) If you set $t=0$ you get $x=y=0$, not the solution you want. But if you set $t=1$ you get $x=-2, y=1$, a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so well, will definitely be going over it a lot. Sorry to have taken up so much of your time, really appreciate the explanation though.